# Is there a way to change USB device descriptor on computer side?

Tags: windows, usb, uart

I am designing a peripheral that draws power from USB port while communicating with a program on Windows. I am planning to use a cheap IC for it (CH340G),  however it's configured to open the port in low power mode by default, by setting the `MaxPower` parameter to `0x30` (96 mA) and it cannot be configured from the IC side. I would save a lot of money if I could change this parameter from computer side.

Can this be done, or should I look for another chip?

Comment: There is a site about electronics on SE, perhaps better try there

Comment: @Marged yes, but I think this requires particular knowledge on Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, USB descriptors are read from the device by the host and there is no standard way in the USB protocol to change them.  You have to change the hardware and/or firmware of the device to change the descriptors.