# How is a device descriptor created and loaded on a new USB device so Windows will recognize it?

Tags: usb, microcontroller

I have this device that has a micro usb soldered onto it.  When I plug it into my computer, Windows throws the error, "Device descriptor request failed".  I believe this is because there is no device descriptor on the device, so the request returns nothing.

My question is:
How can I load a device descriptor onto the device so Windows will be able to enumerate it in the future?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to change USB device descriptor on computer side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52150849/is-there-a-way-to-change-usb-device-descriptor-on-computer-side)

Comment: The answer depends on how your device is implemented.  If it has a microcontroller, maybe you can find the datasheet and learn how to develop firmware for the microcontroller.  There is too little information here for anyone to help with that.